# Ursina's PlatformerController has problems accepting and registering 2 inputs at once

Tags: input, ursina

I am busy creating a 2D platformer game using the platformercontroller2d module. The module has problems if i give the window a x changing movement and a jump movement. Multiple x changing keys(input) work together, but this case does not work. To get the jump movement to work no other keys(input) must be pressed. For example:

```
from ursina import *
player =PlatformerController()
```

This code does not fix my problem.

I have tried using seperate input calls like such:

```
from ursina import *
player=PlatformerController()
def input(key):
   if key=='space':
      player.jump()
```

This also won't allow me to use both keys at the same time. How can i use multiple inputs to effect the player's movement without having to let go of one?

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. The solution was to corp the image down to its (works only on cubic' pixels / shape of set sprite. Then ursina takes care of the rest. weird bug.